# Clone a title copies all titles to a div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to a clone a title from a div into another div but it clones all the titles into a div. Is there a way to clone a title into another div based on which item was clicked?

Code:

```js
$(".front-playpause").on("click", function() {
   $(".ep-title").clone().appendTo($(".package"));
});
```

```css
.front-playpause {background:black;width:10px;height:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<article>
<div class="front-playpause"></div>
<div class="ep-id-right">
<div class="ep-num">episode number</div>
<h1 class="ep-title">title post</h1>
 </div>
</article>

<article>
<div class="front-playpause"></div>
<div class="ep-id-right">
<div class="ep-num">episode number</div>
<h1 class="ep-title">title post</h1>
 </div>
</article>

<article>
<div class="front-playpause"></div>
<div class="ep-id-right">
<div class="ep-num">episode number</div>
<h1 class="ep-title">title post</h1>
 </div>
</article>

<div class="package">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this` keyword instead of using the `classname`while cloning. When you use `classname` it clones all the elements with that class. `this` will refer to the current HTML element.

```js
$(".front-playpause").on("click", function() {
   $(".package").append($(this).parent().find('.ep-title').html());
});
```

```css
.front-playpause {background:black;width:10px;height:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<article>
<div class="front-playpause"></div>
<div class="ep-id-right">
<div class="ep-num">episode number</div>
<h1 class="ep-title">title post</h1>
 </div>
</article>

<article>
<div class="front-playpause"></div>
<div class="ep-id-right">
<div class="ep-num">episode number</div>
<h1 class="ep-title">title post</h1>
 </div>
</article>

<article>
<div class="front-playpause"></div>
<div class="ep-id-right">
<div class="ep-num">episode number</div>
<h1 class="ep-title">title post</h1>
 </div>
</article>

<div class="package">

</div>
```

Comment: How do you copy the text inside `ep-title` instead of the entire div. The above is an example and the actual code is too long to paste. Has other divs inside them

Comment: @GregorySchultz updated my answer. Please accept and upvote the answer if it helped :)

Comment: I've update my question. Wasn't working so now I've updated to include the code being used instead of a sample. Can you update your answer with the new code.

Comment: @GregorySchultz  Updated my answer again.Previously you kept the title div in the same div on which you had the `onclick` listener. Now it's outside of that. That's why the previous code was not working :)

Comment: @GregorySchultz  Glad I helped :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161345/discussion-between-gregory-schultz-and-sanchit-patiyal).